Gitlab CI job base image from private GCP artifact registry using WIF
Is there a way to use an image from a private artifact registry if I can't use service account keys with DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG?
I tried logging in with WIF in a previous job and passing the docker config as an artifact, but it didn't work.
I can't use the Gitlab registry to store the image.
Example:
docker-login:
  # this authenticates correctly with WIF
  extends: .gcp-login
  script:
    - gcloud auth print-access-token | docker login -u oauth2accesstoken --password-stdin europe-west4-docker.pkg.dev
    - echo "DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG=$(cat ~/.docker/config.json)" >> build.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env
    paths:
      - ~/.docker/config.json

actual-job:
  needs:
    - job: docker-login
      artifacts: true
  image: europe-west4-docker.pkg.dev/.../my_private_image:1.0
  script:
    - echo "hello"


Can you provide the error message you encountered when trying to pull the image from the Google Artifact Registry? Have a look at this document

This was the error:
ERROR: Job failed: failed to pull image "myimage" with specified policies [if-not-present]: Error response from daemon: Head "myimage": denied: Unauthenticated request. Unauthenticated requests do not have permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" on resource myimage.
I checked the document. Our current Gitlab version doesn't have that integration, but anyway I don't know how that would help. I need to use the pulled image as a base image.

That solution that you are trying to use can only be used in dind solutions, when building another image or copying in image from a registry to another, not for the base image.
Based on the documentation, we have 3 solutions

To access private container registries, the GitLab Runner process can
use:
1. Statically defined credentials. That is, a username and password for a specific registry.
2. Credentials Store. For more information, see the relevant Docker documentation.
3. Credential Helpers. For more information, see the relevant Docker documentation. 


We cannot use the first one, as

To define which option should be used, the runner process reads the
configuration in this order:
A DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG CI/CD variable.
A DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG environment variable set in the runner’s config.toml file.
A config.json file in $HOME/.docker directory of the user running the process. If the --user flag is provided to run the child processes


To use the 3rd solution, create a CI/CD variable DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG with the content of the Docker configuration file as the value:
{
  "credHelpers": {
    "europe-west4-docker.pkg.dev": "gcr",
  }
}

Then make sure docker-credential-gcr is installed and available in the GitLab Runner $PATH, not base image $PATH. For example:
VERSION=2.1.25
OS=linux  # or "darwin" for OSX, "windows" for Windows.
ARCH=amd64  # or "386" for 32-bit OSs

curl -fsSL "https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/docker-credential-gcr/releases/download/v${VERSION}/docker-credential-gcr_${OS}_${ARCH}-${VERSION}.tar.gz" \
| tar xz docker-credential-gcr \
&& chmod +x docker-credential-gcr && sudo mv docker-credential-gcr /usr/bin/

Then we need to provide the credentials. By default, the helper searches for GCR credentials in the following order:

In a JSON file whose path is specified by the
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.
In a JSON file in a location known to the helper. On Windows, this
is %APPDATA%/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json. On other
systems, $HOME/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json.

GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable can be passed to the job, and it will use the container.

Thank you, I will try this out. So I should log in with WIF in a previous job, set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and pass it in a dotenv artifact to the job using the GAR image, right?

It didn't work, same error:
ERROR: Job failed: failed to pull image .. denied: Unauthenticated request

I am using it for aws, and it is working. This is the official doc: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#use-credential-helpers. are your credentials ok? have you tested it outside gitlab runner?
